# Cannot modify a value type return value of `UnityEngine.Transform.position'. Consider storing the value in a temporary variable

Tags: unity, c#, transformation

I'm getting the following error

> Cannot modify a value type return value of `UnityEngine.Transform.position'. Consider storing the value in a temporary variable

with this code:

```
transform.position = new Vector3(target.position.x, transform.position.y, target.position.z); 
Vector3 desiredPosition = new Vector3(transform.position.x , target.position.y, transform.position.y ); 
Vector3 smoothedPosition = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, desiredPosition, smoothSpeed); 
transform.position += smoothedPosition;
```

Comment: This needs substantial improvement as a question.

Comment: I want the camera to have Lerp on the y axis but not on the x and z.

Comment: The code so far.        transform.position = new Vector3(target.position.x, transform.position.y, target.position.z);

        //gameObject.transform.position.x = target.transform.position.x;

        //Vector3 actualPositionY = transform.position.y;
        Vector3 desiredPosition = new Vector3(transform.position.x , target.position.y, transform.position.y );
        Vector3 smoothedPosition = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, desiredPosition, smoothSpeed);
        transform.position += smoothedPosition;

        
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to modify the `transform.position` property, you have to modify the `transform.position` property: it's values are effectively read-only.  This is due to the fact that Unity Vectors themselves are *value types* and not instanced objects.  What you're trying to do is similar to doing `4 += 1` which makes no sense.

```
Vector3 pos = transform.position;
pos.x = target.transform.position.x;
transform.position = pos;
```

Comment: This is a bit offtopic...but how do I implement this to make so that I have smooth view on y but not on x and z..

Comment: Vector3 pos = transform.position;
        pos.x = target.position.x;
        pos.y = target.position.y;
        pos.z = target.position.z + offsetZ;

        Vector3 desiredPosition = new Vector3(pos.x + offsetX, 
        target.position.y, pos.z + offsetZ );
        Vector3 smoothedPosition = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, 
        desiredPosition, smoothSpeed);
        transform.position = desiredPosition;

Comment: You don't need `desiredPosition` there at all, that's what `pos` is doing. With your `desiredPosition` value, you've added offsetZ twice (you already added it to pos.z on the previous line). Then, you create a lerp value (`smoothedPosition`) and then don't do anything with it.

Comment: New code:        Vector3 pos = transform.position;
        pos.x = target.position.x;
        pos.y = target.position.y;
        pos.z = target.position.z + offsetZ;

        Vector3 smoothedPosition = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, pos, smoothSpeed);
        transform.position = smoothedPosition;

Comment: I dont want the x,z to have lerp, just the y...how do i do that?

Comment: Don't modify the x and z values of pos.

Comment: :)))) But I still want it to move with the player I just dont want the smothing effect,

Comment: I found the solution.I made a second script and typed in this:    void Update () {
        Vector3 pos = transform.position;
        pos.x = target.position.x + offsetX;
        pos.z = target.position.z + offsetZ;
        transform.position = pos;
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

You can only store whole vectors to gameObject.transform.position

Position is read-only in all other contexts.

Comment: I am new to coding...can you explain more...or what I need to change.Thanks

Comment: Yeah, let me get to a computer and I'll suggest an edit to the question, and go into more detail.

Comment: Draco beat me to the full explanation, but yes that's what I meant be read-only. You can only set values to it, not updated values in it.

Comment: :) I dont want the x,z to have lerp, just the y...how do i do that?